# List the components of an array created from user input

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to list the components of an array that is created from Scanner input.
Example...

```
 System: Enter a list of words:

 User: The weather is nice today

 System: [The, weather, is, nice, today]
```

My code is as follows,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayListPractice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> word=new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter a list of words:");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
        String n = keyboard.next();
       
        while(keyboard.hasNext()){
            word.add(keyboard.next());
        }
        System.out.println(word);
   }
}
```

My problem is that the scanner keeps waiting for input and therefore doesn't display any output. I've also tried different for-loops but haven't been able to figure those out. An example of one I've tried is listed below. This one only displays the first two words inputted by the user

```
        for (int i=0; I<n.length(); i++){
            word.add(n);
            n = keyboard.next();
        }
        System.out.println("a) \n"+word);
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674887/9144250)

Comment: what about looping and going like "type a new word or press 'enter' to exit"

Comment: Thanks @elpidaguy, but this is for a coding class and we haven't been taught "split" yet so unfortunately I can't use it

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I know how to do that, but we have a very specific template to follow which doesn't include an exit term. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the while loop here. Just take **the line** of the user's input as a `String` and then you can **split** it into an array of words using `String.split()`.

```
System.out.println("Enter a list of words:");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
String line = keyboard.nextLine();
String[] words = line.split(" ");

for (String word : words)
 System.out.println(word);
```

Output:

```
Enter a list of words:
Hello I am who I am
Hello
I
am
who
I
am
```

### Alternative for coding class

```
System.out.println("Enter a list of words:");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

String word = "quit";

do{
    word = keyboard.next();

    if (!word.equals("quit"))
        words.add(word);

}while (!word.equals("quit"));

for (String w : words)
    System.out.println(w);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Themelis! Unfortunately, this is for a coding class and we haven't been taught "split" yet so I can't use it

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?